# Warning Symbol on Nippy Junior+

Tags: side-effects, med-symbol-abbreviations, nurse-practitioner, proper-use, mechanical-ventilation

One of our clients has recently been put onto a nippy junior plus positive pressure ventilator. Just to the left of the left of the settings lock symbol is the symbol shown below. I would like to know what this symbol indicates. It is not explained in the manual (http://nippyventilator.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NIPPY-Junior-Manual.pdf) and the nurse who trained our staff didn't know either

[image: Symbol]

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the symbol on page 5 of the quick reference guide (http://nippyventilator.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NIPPY-Junior-Quick-Reference-Guide.pdf) for the ventilator. It is just an indicator that the disconnect alarm has been set to low sensitivity.

Comment: You should accept your answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory I can't do until tomorrow, but I shall, thanks